# <picture> element and srcset

Tags: image, srcset

I prefer to use the `<picture>` element to `srcset` because I can use WebP with a fallback to JPG.  I cannot do this with `srcset` which is a shame.

However, I prefer `srcset` because it has the ability to change image by resolution e.g. 2x, 3x

1. Is there a way to combine these two options so I can get the best of both worlds.
2. Why wouldn't I be able to use `srcset` for art direction as this is often used as the main reason to use `<picture>` but I don't see why I couldn't do this with srcset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact combine srcset with the picture element and use both features as so

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 650px)" 
    srcset="images/kitten-stretching.png,
            images/kitten-stretching@1.5x.png 1.5x,  
            images/kitten-stretching@2x.png 2x">
</picture>
```

I still don't know why you wouldn't use srcset for art direction as it seems possible.